# Django: DecimalField values displaying

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model with `DecimalField`:

```
points_player1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I displaying this field in template, it always shows values like `0.0` or `1.0` etc.
But I want to make this behavior more user-friendly:

1. If user input, for example, is `1` it displays `1` (now its 1.0).
2. If user input is `1.5` it should displays `1.5`.
3. By-default value is `0`, not `0.0`.

What is the best way to make this? Is `DecimalField` is right choice for my case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do  `{{decimal_field|floatformat}}` in the template, which will round off and show ".0" only when necessary.

More reference [template - floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#floatformat)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new model field

```
class DecimalFieldNormalized(models.DecimalField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, *args):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return value.normalize()
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can modify the model save method if for some reason you can't/don't want to use django templating, adding this to the bottom of your model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.points_player1 = float(self.points_player1)
    super(YourModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Didn't tryed it , but it should work.